# Word play: "Easy peasy" analog

Tags: words, expressions

We have:

> Easy peasy + lemon squeezy (+ additional rhymes)

I've come across this expression:

> らくしょう + かいしょう + ??しょう

Where I was unable to clearly identify the third element, but it sounds like じょ or じょう

My candidates for the words are 楽勝、快勝、常勝

Since I was unable to find expressions corresponding to them [(from tangorin)](http://tangorin.com/examples/%E6%A5%BD%E5%8B%9D%E5%BF%AB%E5%8B%9D) [(from alc)](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%A5%BD%E5%8B%9D%E5%BF%AB%E5%8B%9D&ref=sa), I decided to post this question.

1. What are the words (Did I get them right?)
2. Is this expression recognizable? Is it common or uncommon usage?
3. Are there other expressions to convey "easy peasy"

Comment: 楽勝快勝こんちくしょう？No probably not, but that's what came to mind, and I kind of like the 語呂.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course the individual words are very common, but personally I do not recognize this as a fixed expression. I found [one person](http://namira229.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1066.html) who wrote a blog entry titled “圧勝。楽勝。快勝。”, and [another person](http://ncc1701.jugem.jp/?eid=3188) with “楽勝。快勝。圧勝。”. Yet [another person](http://www.tfm.co.jp/lock/staff/onair/2010/1109/) seems to have used “楽勝快勝優秀賞” as a radio name. Could it be that what you heard was a one-off — something just made up by the person?

There are several Japanese expressions that are similar to *easy peasy*:

1. ちょちょいのちょい
2. 屁{へ}のカッパ (or カッパの屁)
3. お茶{ちゃ}の子さいさい
4. 余裕{よゆう}のよっちゃん

All of them except #1 may sound a little dated though. #4 is a lame Showa-era joke, but I bet people who've heard of it will find it funny in an ironic, hipster way by now. Also I might add 朝飯前{あさめしまえ} (lit. *before breakfast*) or 屁でもない (lit. *not even a fart*), but those seem more like metaphorical idioms akin to “piece of cake”, rather than a word play like “easy peasy”.

Answer (score 1):

1.楽勝 means " easy victory". 快勝 means "good victory" and it may not easily win. 常勝(じょうしょう) means that " always win".

2.They are recognizable and common usage.

3.I don't come across my mind now.